# How to integrate mocha unit tests in webpack 2?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webpack-2

I looked at the webpack documentation but could not find any information on loading unit tests . The idea is to not start the server when a test is broken. Is it possible to implement this in webpack 2?

Answer (score 0):

if you are migrating from webpack1 to webpack2 , this issue may help you:
https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2711